# Using Out-File to have a date variable within the name for the file

Tags: windows, powershell, datetime, winapi, powershell-remoting

I am trying to use Out-File to have a date variable within the name for the file.
But, getting an exception as below

```
$EndDate = get-date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
Out-File -FilePath "C:\output\$host-$EndDate.json

Out-File : The given path's format is not supported.
At E:\sample.ps1:442 char:69
+ ... MaxValue) | Out-File -FilePath "E:\output\$serverHostName ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Comment: There's not much in your question to go on, but 2 comments: 1) `$Host` is an automatic (reserved) variable, so you don't want to assign a value to it. 2) You can string formatting (`-f` operator) to make your code more readable; e.g.: `Out-File ("C:\output\{0}-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.json" -f $serverHostName,(Get-Date))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Out-File -FilePath "C:\output\$host-$EndDate.json"
```

Make use of the [format (-f) operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx):

```
$EndDate = get-date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
$myFileName = 'C:\output\{0}-{1}.json' -f $host, ($EndDate.ToString() -replace ':','')  -replace '\s','' 
Out-File -filepath $myFileName
```

Also, you may need to use the [New-Item command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6) instead of Out-File, if your directory doesn't already exist. Your error seems to indicate that the directory may not be available when creating the file.

```
New-Item -path $myFileName -Force
```

As Bill Stewart pointed out, [`$host` is a reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6), so be careful using it.

Comment: Don't forget `( )` around the string representing the filename.

Comment: `Out-File : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'f' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -FilePath -Force.
At E:\sample.ps1:442 char:127
+ ...  Out-File -FilePath 'E:\output\({0}-{1}).json' -f $server ...
+                                                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand`

Comment: @mealhour it's because of your variables. What's inside of $host and $Date ? That will dictate how you create your string....I updated the 2nd example...

Comment: it seems to be an issue with `$Enddate` `$EndDate=get-date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`  Do I need to change it to String?

Comment: @mealhour yes, I think a String would be best. see the updated example.

Comment: I am getting this error after making the update `Out-File : The given path's format is not supported.
At E:\sample.ps1:444 char:69
+ ... rtTo-Json -Depth ([int32]::MaxValue) | Out-File -FilePath $myFileName
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand`

Comment: @mealhour, I think the problem is with spaces and semi-colons from the timestamp inside of the filename. You can remove them with the "replace" flag, see the updated answer.

Comment: @meallhour I have added further instruction for creating new files in directories that dont exist, which I suspect is also part of your issue here.

Comment: @AussieJoe thanks for your help...the file is now getting generated but the name has brackets around it `(abc12.com-2018-05-16193026).json` how to get rid of the brackets?  `

Comment: @meallhour You could try: `Out-File -filepath $myFileName -replace '(','', ')', ''`

Comment: @AussieJoe I am trying `New-Item -path $myFileName -Force -replace '(','', ')', ''` but it is not creating the file

Comment: @meallhour `New-Item -path ($myFileName -replace '(','', ')', '') -Force`

Comment: @AussieJoe it is still not generating the file. I am able to generate it using `New-Item -path $myFileName -Force ` but it has brackets