# PowerShell log filename with datetime issue

Tags: powershell, datetime, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to create a log filename for today date time using powershell command

```
 $date = Get-Date
    $log = "D:\NewFolder\Logs\FixService$date.log"  
    "Write this text to log" >> $log
```

I am getting error as shown below , How to do this?

> ```
>  out-file : The given path's format is not supported.
>     At D:\NewFolder\somefile.ps1:5 char:1
>     + "Write this text to log" >> $log
>     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], NotSupportedException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
> ```

But this works without date in log file name

```
$date = Get-Date  
$log = "D:\Crowdstrike\Logs\FixService.log"   
"Write this to log" >> $log
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Depending on your culture, the `$date` might contain colons (`:`) which aren't supported in a filename, see:  [Allowed characters in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814088/1701026)

Comment: what change i need to make this work?

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Out-File to have a date variable within the name for the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339544/using-out-file-to-have-a-date-variable-within-the-name-for-the-file)

Comment: This worked $date = Get-Date
$DateStr = $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$log = "D:\Crowdstrike\Logs\FixService$DateStr.log"

Comment: Can't post as answer. It's more a hint that this is duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a DateTime in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell)

Comment: yes @harper post that as answer, i will accept

Answer (score 3):

Powershell uses [*`ToString`* method to convert the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent string representation using the specified format and the formatting conventions of the current culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_). You can inspect your current culture by

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.Name
```

Or using `Get-Culture` Cmdlet.
The issue here is that the resultant string contain the characters that are not allowed in filenames. So one solution is to use the format parameter of the `get-date` Cmdlet.

```
Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$LogPath = "C:\Users"

$LogPathName = Join-Path -Path $LogPath -ChildPath "logToday-$(Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyyy').log"
```

Comment: Please mark as answer, if it is unblocked your issue